# Can you please show the community some audit stats?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, statistics, review-suspension

For example:

- What percentage of users that have

  - < 1,000 **reviews** *have been banned 0 times from reviewing, been banned 1 time from reviewing, been banned 2 times, 3 times, 4 times, 5 or more times.*
  - 1,000 - 5,000?
  - 5,000 - 15,000?
  - > 15,000?
- What is the audit pass rate for users with

  - < 1,000 **reviews**?
  - 1,000-5,000?
  - 5,000-15,000?
  - > 15,000?
- What is the audit pass rate for users with

  - < 1,000 **reputation**?
  - 1,000-5,000?
  - 5,000-20,000?
  - 20,000 - 50,000?
  - > 50,000?
- What is the overall audit pass rate for the

  - close votes queue?
  - reopen queue?
  - first posts queue?
  - late answers queue?
  - triage queue?
  - low quality queue?
  - suggested edits queue?

Those are some examples of the data that I think would be very interesting for us to see. Really though, I'd just like to see some cool audit stats and think others would as well. Please provide us with some amazing data about the audits!

Comment: That (and maybe some additional stats) could potentially solve the endless debate if higher rep users should get more moderation privileges.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't have time to put together a nice report for this, so here's a big ol' stats dump for the past 365 days:

```
Review Audits Completed 
----------------------- 
307384                  

Review Audits Failed PctFailed 
-------------------- --------- 
25944                8.44 %    

Queue             Audits Audits Failed PctFailed 
----------------- ------ ------------- --------- 
Close Votes       30170  3168          10.50 %   
First Post        63657  7661          12.03 %   
Late Answer       31603  4505          14.25 %   
Low Quality Posts 56850  2147          3.78 %    
Reopen Vote       14719  1860          12.64 %   
Suggested Edit    70428  4202          5.97 %    
Triage            39957  2401          6.01 %    

Reviews by User Audits Audits Failed PctFailed 
--------------- ------ ------------- --------- 
500             60536  8534          14.10 %   
1000            37582  4057          10.80 %   
1500            29651  2354          7.94 %    
2000            22992  1904          8.28 %    
2500            19817  1487          7.50 %    
3000            16271  1013          6.23 %    
3500            14402  872           6.05 %    
4000            8899   680           7.64 %    
4500            9999   655           6.55 %    
5000            6900   485           7.03 %    
5500            7208   442           6.13 %    
6000            7278   510           7.01 %    
6500            5646   353           6.25 %    
7000            3523   218           6.19 %    
7500            5641   251           4.45 %    
8000            5151   237           4.60 %    
8500            5259   345           6.56 %    
9000            2975   181           6.08 %    
9500            2296   85            3.70 %    
10000           3113   185           5.94 %    
10500           1183   48            4.06 %    
11000           285    20            7.02 %    
11500           2456   108           4.40 %    
12000           992    72            7.26 %    
12500           1259   57            4.53 %    
13000           472    15            3.18 %    
13500           1512   96            6.35 %    
14000           576    33            5.73 %    
14500           582    24            4.12 %    
15000           26     0             0.00 %    
15500           965    39            4.04 %    
16000           1940   112           5.77 %    
16500           63     5             7.94 %    
17000           1405   4             0.28 %    
18000           164    3             1.83 %    
18500           268    1             0.37 %    
19000           656    28            4.27 %    
19500           2040   45            2.21 %    
20000           15401  386           2.51 %    

Reviewer Reputation Audits Audits Failed PctFailed 
------------------- ------ ------------- --------- 
1000                26780  3644          13.61 %   
2000                46776  5526          11.81 %   
3000                62541  5000          7.99 %    
4000                41980  3133          7.46 %    
5000                22508  1743          7.74 %    
6000                18288  1363          7.45 %    
7000                12161  834           6.86 %    
8000                9829   620           6.31 %    
9000                6473   408           6.30 %    
10000               6361   246           3.87 %    
11000               4724   328           6.94 %    
12000               4417   391           8.85 %    
13000               3395   231           6.80 %    
14000               2159   179           8.29 %    
15000               3059   184           6.02 %    
16000               1296   71            5.48 %    
17000               1398   95            6.80 %    
18000               2826   172           6.09 %    
19000               1593   207           12.99 %   
20000               28820  1569          5.44 %    

Reviews by User Bans AvgBansPerUser  
--------------- ---- --------------- 
500             1622 1.607532210109  
1000            1202 2.380198019801  
1500            795  2.713310580204  
2000            501  3.150943396226  
2500            416  3.081481481481  
3000            235  2.901234567901  
3500            242  3.226666666666  
4000            192  3.840000000000  
4500            172  3.583333333333  
5000            116  3.314285714285  
5500            114  4.384615384615  
6000            142  3.944444444444  
6500            90   3.913043478260  
7000            50   4.545454545454  
7500            42   2.210526315789  
8000            64   4.923076923076  
8500            74   4.352941176470  
9000            27   3.000000000000  
9500            15   3.000000000000  
10000           27   3.375000000000  
10500           3    3.000000000000  
11000           3    1.500000000000  
11500           16   4.000000000000  
12000           19   6.333333333333  
12500           15   3.000000000000  
13000           1    1.000000000000  
13500           38   6.333333333333  
14000           2    2.000000000000  
14500           3    1.500000000000  
15500           16   16.000000000000 
16000           13   3.250000000000  
16500           1    1.000000000000  
17000           2    2.000000000000  
19000           5    2.500000000000  
19500           13   6.500000000000  
20000           51   3.642857142857
```

Where reviews / rep are broken into buckets, the final bucket contains everything >= 20,000. Because, scrolling.

Comment: So which 19ker is failing all the audits?

Comment: Damn 15.5kers. They need to be exiled.

Comment: If y'all are gonna take something away from all this, it should probably be: SO is frick'n huge; there are thousands of audits a day and plenty of bans to go with them. The handful of complaints here on meta isn't really much, considering.

Comment: In the breakdown of failures by reputation, is this based on the rep users had when they failed the audit, or the rep they have now?

Comment: The rep they have now, @Reto. The other calculation is unbearably slow.

Comment: The real takeaway is that reputation is completely irrelevant when it comes to reviews. With only a max of 2000 coming from edits, that leaves the vast majority of reputation coming from asking and answering questions, something a user is able to do without knowing how to review at all. Having "trusted user" privileges means nothing if you can't prove that you can be trusted.

Comment: @BoltClock - I believe you are confusing review counts in the data for reputation. Only one of these tables addresses the relationship between reputation and review audit success. There is a significant drop in review audit failure after the 3000 reputation mark. It drops to single from double digits.

Comment: So if even users with lots of reviews and lots of rep are still "failing" audits at around a 2-3% rate, maybe we can conclude that about 2-3% of the audit questions are faulty.

Comment: Maybe. Then again, I'm familiar with a couple of those users; they should probably be failing more.