# A staging area for telling new users how they can make their questions better

Tags: feature-request, new-users, quality-improvement

When looking through the Android tag, I see a lot of questions where there is an issue explained and often "please help" or something similar is written there. No stacktrace, no code, just "here is an issue, please fix".

There are warnings that tell the new user about these things, but they seem to ignore them, meaning there are a ton of questions that get downvotes because they (most of the time) just have some code and an explanation of the issue (it crashes when I do [blank]). And this type of question leads to meta questions asking [if it is OK to downvote their first question/answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268006/is-it-ok-to-downvote-or-close-new-users-first-questions).

But the reality is that there are so many new users who write bad questions, and I believe it may be because they aren't introduced into the standard. They get a problem and if they are new to development, they panic and go to Stack Overflow, showing little to no code and saying "help me".

In a few hours I can flag about 2-3 questions asking about suggestions to libraries, IDE's "is this [tool] better than this one? What are good alternatives?". Most of the new users' questions (at least in the Android tag) are poor quality and often receive a lot of downvotes. Most of the new users' questions I have seen on the Android tag have been off-topic, poorly researched, or in the Android Documentation (the official one, not the one here on Stack Overflow).

So could it be an idea to prevent the first questions from being viewed by anyone else, but only to those in the review queue, to ensure that these questions and these users get a start that doesn't involve downvoting and closing/deleting their questions/answers? And in general prevent low quality, duplicated, and poorly researched questions from being visible on Stack Overflow.

---

It will be a sort-of staging area for new posts by new users. Any new users who haven't posted a question/answer yet should have their post enter the staging area, so that it isn't visible until it is approved. This will force new users to learn how you ask a question here on Stack Overflow, and what the standard is. In doing this, those who will not edit their questions can get a warning or something similar, but not be allowed to have their question published.

This is, however, a raw idea. It does need refining, But the basic idea is to make sure every new user who asks or answers a question knows how to do it. I have seen people adding comments as answers because they think it is a forum (like Reddit), and these types of thing are what the staging area will work to avoid. It will be like another review queue, but there should be communication between the post's creator and the reviewers.

---

As mentioned in one answer, it would also decrease the close vote queue, and also better categorize the questions: Are these bad because the user doesn't know better, or because the user didn't care or forgot to do research?

Comment: AFAIK new users already get a lot of guidance, in the form of tooltips. But people ignore these things. I guess we're so used to being bombarded with popups and tooltips, that people just dismiss them without reading :-(

Comment: That is why I suggest adding a que for the first posts(questions and answers) - these should be controlled, and if there is something wrong, the user should get a detailed reason to understand and avoid these things in the future. Call it a question staging area, designed to help new users write as good questions as possible

Comment: What about making at least one {Code} section mandatory for questions with specific tags like android, ios, c#? I mean those tags that are clearly related to anything "code"

Comment: @Grisgram There will always be exceptions. Forcing users to add some code, will only lead to them finding creative ways around the arbitrary restriction.

Comment: @LunarWatcher Triage was meant to work like that, except that in Triage, questions that don't have enough info should be closed. Given that Triage (and it's companion Help & Improvement) don't work very well... maybe this idea for a queue would be a nice alternative. Main difference with First Posts being that no other users see the post until it's been reviewed.

Comment: And there are some questions that doesn't involve code at all(Example: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43341300/6296561)) All though it isn't the first post from a user, it still doesn't contain code because it is related to an issue that is on-topic but doesn't involve code. The question (tagged android) with probably most upvotes on the ANdroid tag asks for the difference between px, sp, dp and so on. No code is involved there either. FOrcing users to add code is wrong, because there are questions that are good that doesn't involve code

Comment: And questions like t[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343411/error-in-my-navigation-drawer) that have a little code, and shows that there isn't done any research is what the goal is to avoid. (Continuation from my last comment): Questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android) that have no code, but show a clear issue is why we cannot force users to show code. And the tooltips are sort off like the terms of service: no one reads them because you don't want to waste time on it

Comment: 'help new users write as good questions' a waste of time that could be spend on answering those few questions that show some effort and respect for other SO users.

Comment: `'help new users write as good questions' a waste of time that could be spend on answering those few questions that show some effort and respect for other SO users.` - So instead you suggest we answer those terrible questions that show up and get closed? This queue would be for the first post of each type(question and answer) and the first time, the users would get a free pass to screw up. If they do the same on their next post(s) after getting suggestions on how they can edit their posts to become better, then there is no need to try. IF they cannot understand the rules after having it(1/2)

Comment: (2/3) gotten a guide on them, there is no need to try again. If the users doesn't understand the rules the first time, give them a free pass and try to get them to understand them. If they fail the second time, then it has been tried to get them to understand, but they still don't understand. The suggested review queue would help users in their first post, in an attempt to lower the one-rep terrible questions that are downvoted and flagged. Do you know what is a waste of time? Reviewing the close vote queue knowing 90% of those flagged are posts from new members. By the time they get into(2/3)

Comment: (3/3) the review queue for first posts, it is already too late. The bad posts will get downvotes and flags(if applicable) and the close vote queue grows. This is basically an attempt to separate those who are bad because it is the first post and those who are bad because there isn't any research before asking the question. Good posts will just be approved and that's the end of that. Bad posts will make the OP learn what is a good post and what isn't, and hopefully improve it. And as @SLBarth wrote in h*s answer: If the OP doesn't respond for a time, the question is scrapped. It is an attempt

Comment: To improve the new users to prevent that 99% of posts from the new users are down-vote and flag-worthy.

Comment: I don't think it should be limited to new users. I think if anyone posts a question that ends up becoming heavily downvoted/closed then your next question would go through the review process as well.

Comment: I don't know how many questions are asked every day, not to forget every hour, but adding all of these to the review queue would mean questions may never be published.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're proposing is a new review queue. A bit like the "First Posts" review queue, except that questions in the new queue are not visible to other users until they've been reviewed.

**And this new queue could greatly relieve the burden of the Close Votes queue!**

Input to this new queue would be the questions that are tagged with a programming language or platform, where the user has not supplied a code sample. There might be a few more criteria, a few heuristics that suggest that a question can only be improved by the OP.

When the question enters the queue, it won't be visible on the main site. (I believe Triage does this, too). This is how the queue is different from the existing First Posts queue.

A review then consists of a user commenting; possibly with a few pro-forma comments, like asking for a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example.

- If the OP then edits their question, the question leaves the queue and goes to the main site.
- If the OP does not respond in (for example) 2 days, the question gets kicked off the site.

This queue could then replace the Triage queue and the Help & Improvement queue.

My main concern would be the reviewers. A queue that relies on giving guidance, by its nature, cannot really have audits. Maybe a review in this queue should not count until the question is edited by the OP *and* gets an upvote, from someone other than the reviewer.

Comment: If that review will be considered, then please restrict it with a higher reputation level than the Triage queue. The amount of wrong reviews there is alarming. And afair there was a statistic in one of the meta questions showing the the amount of incorrect reviews drops with higher reputation.

Comment: This is the goal, yes. Relieve the Close Vote queue would be a bonus. There are so many new questions that have a problem that may not be documented anywhere, but because there aren't enough details they are downvoted and voted to close. And if the new users doesn't get a ton of downvotes and closed questions, they will become valuable members of the Stack Overflow community

Comment: @Tom I'd be interested to see that statistic. What I'd really want in the review queues (apart from a [tutorial for new reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336206/812149)) is to limit their reviews to, say 5. And then gradually increase a reviewer's review slots, if they continue to review properly. Like the way flags work.

Comment: @LunarWatcher My suggestion for an implementation of this queue is still a little away from what you suggest. I've gone for "comment, and wait for upvote" because these can be verified easily. What you suggest is more interactive. I'd like to see if someone has a good idea for implementing that.

Comment: My idea was a somewhat raw idea. It needed some refining, which you have presented. Having some automatic flags is a good idea, but having it somewhat interactive is also important. But basically training the new users to write good questions/answers is the goal. Having user-user interaction would be a good idea, because any questions the OP may have will be taken instantly(or as fast as possible, at least) and make sure that when the question comes out of the staging area, it isn't worth an instant downvote or flag.

Comment: @S.L.Barth "Statistic" might be a stretch, it was a SEDE query about the amount of failed audits grouped by reputation levels: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292174/can-you-please-show-the-community-some-audit-stats.

Comment: @Tom Thanks! But it really just says that higher rep users are better at not failing audits. It suggests there is a correlation between rep and proper reviewing. But it could also be that the high-rep users are more familiar with the tricks and tools to avoid audits.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Maybe. But I also see bad reviews, then I see a question on meta like "why was this approved" and there is (almost) always a use with <2k reputation part of approvers. And it gets worse in documentation reviews, but this has been discussed several times :D.

Comment: If we can make a new queue(or edit an existing) that makes the first post from new users invisible until approved, it would also be a part of lowering the close flag queue. Then everything that would be in the close flag queue would be bad questions - not because the OP misunderstood the SO rules, scope, etc - but because they are actually bad. Lacking research, for an instance

Answer (score 5):

> Most of the new users questions (at least in the Android tag) are poor quality

This is indeed not unique to the Android tag.

> So could it be an idea to prevent the first questions from being viewed by anyone else, but only to those in the review queue, to ensure that these questions and these users get a start that doesn't involve downvoting and closing/deleting their questions/answers?

But we *already have that*. There's plenty of queues where questions end up under certain circumstances, which are kind-of hidden from the rest of the site until enough people approved the question.

Enter robo-reviewers and barely competent programmers who just want to build a resume using Stack Overflow's reputation system who approve anything that barely resembles a question (*"But it contained a question mark!"*) so they can Google the question's title and copy-paste the first hit in an answer to that question.

I don't have the numbers handy and I don't feel like writing any SEDE-SQL at the moment, but the ratio of *"people who can objectively assess a question's quality and uniqueness"* vs *"people who want their damn problem fixed"* is about 1:100, or so it feels like.

So in order to somewhat reliably have people determining whether a question is "worthy" of being visible to everyone, you're going to need a whole lot more of competent people - and those people have better things to do than sift through the questions that are being asked on Stack Overflow nowadays, as the *"good question"* vs *"bad question"* ration also lies around 1:100.

I don't want to sound negative about the review queues, but the people who dedicate their valuable time to those are better off doing something more productive, as all questions closed and removed from the various queues together form a mere drop in the ocean.

As for your question: yes, the solution to all our problems would be to by default hide or close new questions from users who haven't proven yet that they can ask good questions, and I'm pretty sure equivalent features have been requested before. However, there's nowhere near enough qualified users to review the influx of new questions.

Comment: I did write `at least` because I don't look a lot on the other tags. I stick to a few tags, but I do understand that this is guaranteeably not limited to a single tag. But the current queues does not place the questions in there automatically, and most of the new questions from new users results in downvotes and close votes. Rarely spam votes, but those exist too. Those who actually have issues with something get a bad start on Stack Overflow. The queue I am suggesting has the intent of lowering the amount of bad questions, and increasing the amount of good questions. Or at least raise (1/2)

Comment: _"But the current queues does not place the questions in there automatically"_ - AFAIK they do. The system can recognize low-quality questions and sometimes decides to put them in Triage, where they'll be hidden from most people, at least on their frontpage.

Comment: Looking through the triage queue, and most of the questions are from first-time posters. There are 180 posts in the queue(at this time) and if over 50% of those are 1 rep users with downvotes, it is already too late - they get downvotes and don't know why, the question gets closed and they don't know why. This is an attempt to learn them to get it right the first time, and not on the second post.

Comment: Furthermore, there are 8.6k close votes. I cannot review in there yet, but how many of those would you guess are new user posts?

Comment: @Lunar but again, if you want to protect newcomers by having every first question of every newcomer reviewed by a more experienced member before it's visible to everyone, then again, see my answer: we haven't got enough experienced members for that to ever work. The members who _would_ want to review that, would be in it for the badges, and not with the greater good in mind. Giving honest feedback on a question takes a couple of minutes at least, and that's only if the asker sticks around to respond to questions.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question: My idea is raw. Not refined to handle things like that. As mentioned in @SLBarth's answer: `A review then consists of a user commenting; possibly with a few pro-forma comments, like asking for a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example.`. That is a more refined version of the idea,  and would still help the new users write a good first question.